# Php zip проблемы с кириллицей utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, zip

Проблемы с кириллицей при создании архивов посредством php zip. В частности в архив добавляется дамп базы данных в кодировке utf-8. На выходе из архива кодировка ломается.

Пример кода.

```
$archiveName = date('YmdHi') . '-' . APP::$conf['location'][1] . '.zip';


$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($archiveName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

// create recursive directory iterator
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(ROOT), RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);
foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $localPath = explode(ROOT, $filePath);

    if ((strpos($filePath, ROOT . '/logs') !== false) || (strpos($filePath, ROOT . '/tmp') !== false)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        if (is_file($filePath)) {
         //   echo mb_substr($localPath[1], 1)."<br>";
            $zip->addFile(mb_substr($localPath[1],1));
        }
    }
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archiveName));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $archiveName.'"');

readfile($archiveName);
//  unlink($archiveName);
rmdir($backupDir);
exit;
```

Comment: может имя файла нужно escape-ить?

Comment: ломается кодировка имени файла или кодировка внутри файла?

Comment: Это известный баг. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53948